# Should I just snap this metal bit off my iPhone 5?

Tags: hardware, battery, iphone, repair

I'm trying to replace my iPhone 5 battery, but there's this one stupid stripped screw that won't come out of the bottom metal battery cover. Would it be a bad idea to just cut that metal cover off, and maybe replace it with electrical tape? I marked it with red in the picture.

[image: metal part]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule given the low cost of having Apple replace the battery I would normally recommend this, it's then a official product with warranty.

However as you've already got the part and opened the phone this is too late.. It looks like the cover you are trying to remove is the one over the battery connector, this is what prevents your battery from falling out, I don't think tape will cut it. I would suggest trying to get a small flat blade dug in to try and get that screw out and then get a replacement screw.

Be very careful inside there, your handling an unprotected lithium battery, bending it, or puncturing it with the screw driver could result in a plume of horrible smoke and fire from the battery.